Entering data into a power bi column from Power Apps
Is there a way to create a column in a data set in PowerBI that can be linked with a power Apps so someone can input data into power Apps to be reflected into the power BI table
I tried linking the PowerBI to the power Apps but I can only link existing data or fill an Excel sheet table, I want to fill an empty column directly in power BI

No, PBI is not a database, you'll have to add it to an excel file/DB, then refresh it

Cannot. It will need to be PowerApp to datasource, which then PowerBI will import in (or DirectQuery). Eg: Power App to DB, Power BI DirectQuery to DB, near-real-time.

Not directly, but indirectly, yes. Power App can populate a database table, which can then be a source for the Power BI report. You can even embed that Power App in the report itself. With DirectQuery, you should be able to make the Power App refresh PBI visuals.
